# How can I split a string with an exact match of a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I need to split a string to remove any exact matches.

Here's what I tried.

```js
let str = 'a abc a a bac';
let m = 'a';
str.split(m);
```

the result will remove all occurrences of the variable in the str. I need a way to put a variable inside a /^$/ regex to get only the exact matches. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which instances of "a" do you not consider to be an exact match to "a"?

Comment: So this code will remove all a's in the string. What I need is to remove only an exact string of 'a'. So the result should have been 
[abc,bac] 
This is just an example as the point is to remove exact variable from the given string.

Comment: Surround `a` with `\b` then: `\ba\b`.

Comment: Maybe split the whole string into words first and then process the resulting array.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to use only a single `split` for this?

Comment: @InSync Is there a way to that with a variable ? Meaning make a exact match pattern regex with a given variable.

Comment: Use ```new RegExp(`\b${yourVariable}\b`)```. Do note that you need to escape special characters beforehand.

Comment: @InSync that won't work for split.

Comment: Why not? `String#split()` [accepts both strings and `RegExp` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#parameters); in fact, it accepts anything that has a [`[Symbol.split]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/split) method.

Comment: Was just about to post this when this post got closed.     `let str = 'a abc a a bac of da van a';
let m = 'a';
let escUserRx = m.replace( /[\\$()*+\-.?\[\]^{|}]/g, '\\$&');
let Rx = new RegExp(\`(?:\\s+|^)${escUserRx}(?:\\s+${escUserRx})*(?:\\s+|$)\`);
let result = str.split(Rx).filter(Boolean);;
console.log(result);` I guess if it's not closed fast enough, somebody will post a better way to do it.

Comment: Not really a duplicate. Just because something could be solved with a regex doesn't mean it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to split your input into "words", then filter out some of the words. This can be achieved by using `split` followed by `filter`:

```js
const str = 'a abc a a bac';
const m = 'a';
const result = str.split(/\s+/).filter(x => x != m);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'a abc a a bac';
//as you asked a to be in variable
let m = 'a';
//we need to form RegEx with variable
//this expression matches a with word boundry and spaces if you wish to keep spaces just remove |\\s 
let reg = new RegExp('\\b' + m + '\\b|\\s/gm')
console.log(str.split(reg))
```